# Change url (redirection) in asp .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am working on a C# mvc application. In my site I have this url `abc.com/About/WhoWeAre`, where 'About' is the Controller and 'WhoWeAre' is the action name. But i want this url to be returned as `abc.com/About/who-we-are`. The problem is I can't name the action containing '-' in it. I tried `Url Redirection` using `HttpContext Response` but couldn't find a solution.

If I handle the request in Route Config for 'About/who-we-are' and route it to 'About/WhoWeAre' it is working with the required url in the address bar. But when I make request for 'About/WhoWeAre' it returns the page with the same('About/WhoWeAre') url in the address bar, which duplicates the url. How can I redirect?

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 2):

Use ActionName Attribute to map the Url. Below is the example

```
 public class AboutController : Controller
 {

    [ActionName("Who-we-are")]
    public ActionResult WhoWeAre()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```

Comment: It is working for this url : abc.com/About/who-we-are
But doesnt works for  abc.com/About/WhoWeAre

Comment: ActionName attribute only allow to pass one name for one method. If you want to map multiple urls for the same action , then we can define multiple matching routes. Here is the example which maps to your problem http://modernpathshala.com/Forum/Thread/Interview/8482/how-to-configure-multiple-url-with-same-action-name

Comment: Thanks for your help @ashish
I had implemented the method shown in the link.
But my requirement is different, I want the URL displayed on the users browser shouild be abc.com/About/who-we-are no matter what url he enters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ActionName attribute to rename your actions with characters that are disallowed in C# method names.

Comment: Thanks @ScoobyDrew18